# Why can't I declare a friend in one class that is a private member of another class?

Tags: c++, private, friend, member-functions

Given the following code:

```
class Screen;

class WindowMgr
{
    WindowMgr& relocateScreen( int r, int c, Screen& s);
};

class Screen
{
    friend WindowMgr& WindowMgr::relocateScreen( int r, int c, Screen& s);
    // ^ cannot access private member declared in class 'WindowMgr'

    int m_nR,
        m_nC;
};

WindowMgr& WindowMgr::relocateScreen( int r, int c, Screen& s)
{
    s.m_nR = r;
    s.m_nC = c;
    return *this;
}
```

Why can the `Screen` class not declare the `WindowMgr::relocateScreen` member function as a friend? `Screen` is not wanting to *use* this private member-function of another class, but simply wants that function to be able access its own private members.

Making the `relocateScreen` function public might be bad design if it's intented only for use within the `WindowMgr` class. Equally, making `Screen` a friend of `WindowMgr` might be bad design if it is not intented to access private members of `WindowMgr` in any other case.

Where am I going wrong here? What is the correct approach? Am I making a fool of myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The friend declaration doesn't work because `WindowMgr::relocateScreen()` is private to `WindowMgr`.

C++ standard 11.4-7:

> "A name nominated by a friend
>   declaration shall be accessible in the
>   scope of the class containing the
>   friend declaration..."

Personally, I would make `relocateScreen()` a private member function of `Screen` and make `WindowMgr` a `friend` of `Screen`. That way, `WindowMgr` can just call `relocateScreen()` on `Screen` and won't have to touch any of the data members of `Screen`.

Answer (score 0):

The WindowMgr will have to declare Screen as a friend. You can use a forward declaration.

Comment: The forward declaration is already there. In fact if I made class Screen a friend in WindowMgr, the declaration of class Screen would be introduced into the surrounding scope, explicitly removing the need for the forward declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Why not factor the WindowMgr::relocateScreen out into a different class, say WindowMgrFoo witht the 1 relocateScreen function. Delcare WindowMgrFoo a friend of Screen in Screen and have WindowMgr inherit privately from WindowMgrFoo? Or just have WindowMgr have a reference to a WindowMgrFoo, but that you need to change how it's called by users if you make it public.

Answer (score 0):

In Silico - Nice one for citing the standard. Having slept on it I now see the rationale:

By declaring `WindowMgr::relocateScreen` with its paramater list to be a friend in `Screen`, the `Screen` class becomes dependent on the private implementation of the `WindowMgr` class. This violates encapsulation/information hiding.

In order to not violate the tenets of OOD, only public member-functions of class can be declared as friends in another, because otherwise the latter becomes dependent on the private implementation of the former.